# Python - Opening successive Files without physically opening every one

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I am to read a number of files in Python 3.2, say 30-40, and i want to keep the file references in a list

(all the files are in a common folder)

Is there anyway how i can open all the files to their respective file handles in the list, without having to individually open every file via the file.open() function

Comment: ...What? You want to open files without opening them?

Comment: Do you mean without making the calls on the system, or without typing `file.open()` 30-40 times into your code? The former is impossible (the file needs to be accessed to... er, be accessed).

Comment: I meant the latter, that is without having to do the second, typing file.open() that many times into my code

Comment: Then use a loop. If this is new on you, I strongly suggest that you follow a tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple, just use a list comprehension based on your list of file paths. Or if you only need to access them one at a time, use a generator expression to avoid keeping all forty files open at once.

```
list_of_filenames = ['/foo/bar', '/baz', '/tmp/foo']
open_files = [open(f) for f in list_of_filenames]
```

If you want handles on all the files in a certain directory, use the [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) function:

```
import os
open_files = [open(f) for f in os.listdir(some_path)]
```

I've assumed a simple, flat directory here, but **note** that `os.listdir` returns a list of paths to all file objects in the given directory, whether they are "real" files or directories. So if you have directories within the directory you're opening, you'll want to filter the results using `os.path.isfile`:

```
import os
open_files = [open(f) for f in os.listdir(some_path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Also, `os.listdir` only returns the bare filename, rather than the whole path, so if the current working directory is not `some_path`, you'll want to make absolute paths using `os.path.join`.

```
import os
open_files = [open(os.path.join(some_path, f)) for f in os.listdir(some_path) 
              if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

---

With a generator expression:

```
import os
all_files = (open(f) for f in os.listdir(some_path)) # note () instead of []
for f in all_files:
    pass # do something with the open file here.
```

In all cases, **make sure you close the files when you're done with them**. If you can upgrade to Python 3.3 or higher, I recommend you use an [`ExitStack`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) for one more level of convenience .

Comment: The second one's what i was looking for i.e not having to type in each file name individually

Thank you

Comment: And `os.listdir` will return directories which won't open correctly, so you'll probably want to use `os.path.isfile` or equivalent for your example...

Comment: @JonClements I was assuming for simplicity that there were no directories within the target directory, but yes, I'll make a note of that.

Comment: It's a pity that the OP is using Python 3.2 and not Python 3.3, or he might be able to use an `ExitStack`.

Comment: @DSM Yes indeed. Link to `ExitStack` documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack), if anyone is interested. It was introduced in 3.3, and essentially you just wrap a context manager around each of the `open` calls, to get the functionality of a context manager for each file object even though they're created in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

The `os` library (and `listdir` in particular) should provide you with the basic tools you need:

```
import os
print("\n".join(os.listdir())) # returns all of the files (& directories) in the current directory
```

Obviously you'll want to call `open` with them, but this gives you the files in an iterable form (which I think is the crux of the issue you're facing). At this point you can just do a `for` loop and open them all (or some of them).

quick caveat: Jon Clements pointed out in the comments of Henry Keiter's answer that you should watch out for directories, which will show up in `os.listdir` along with files.

Additionally, this is a good time to write in some filtering statements to make sure you only try to open the right kinds of files. You might be thinking you'll only ever have .txt files in a directory **now**, but someday your operating system (or users) will have a clever idea to put something else in there, and that could throw a wrench in your code.

Fortunately, a quick filter can do that, and you can do it a couple of ways (I'm just going to show a regex filter):

```
import os,re
scripts=re.compile(".*\.py$")
files=[open(x,'r') for x in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(x) and scripts.match(x)]
files=map(lambda x:x.read(),files)
print("\n".join(files))
```

Note that I'm not checking things like whether I have permission to access the file, so if I have the ability to see the file in the directory but not permission to read it then I'll hit an exception.